# Issues with Menu Editor in GNOME 3

Tags: linux, gnome, fedora, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm currently using Fedora 16 w/ GNOME 3. I've created a new application entry for Xilinx ISE using Alacarte.

Here it is below:
[image: Alacarte]

The application itself runs perfectly, however there is an issue with what category it was placed it:
[image]

You can see that the applications was placed in the **Other** category, instead of the **Programming** category where I specified it to be placed in. I've also noticed that there was also an **Electronics** category created when I installed the Fedora Electronic Lab tools, but this is not visible.

My question is why are so many of my applications being placed in the **Other** category, and how to I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to open the `.desktop` file that was created and change the `Category=` field.

Comment: @DanD. Where does Alacarte normally store these? All the other ones are in /usr/share/applications it seems.

Comment: The ones that are user created appear in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: @DanD. Well that worked, thanks. I just need to figure out how create new categories I suppose.